# Registering iris after encrypting with fingerprint throws android.security.KeyStoreException: Key user not authenticated

Tags: android, encryption, samsung-mobile, android-keystore, android-biometric-prompt

Using the AndroidX Biometric Prompt on a Samsung S9 (Android 10) works fine in when only fingerprints are registered on the device and we trigger biometrics to encrypt/decrypt a password.

However `android.security.KeyStoreException: Key user not authenticated` is thrown when decrypting the password after irises are registered as well. It makes sense because the key used to decrypt was authenticated only by fingerprint.

Re-encrypting the key after enabling irises has no issue and the exception isn't thrown.

Is there a clean way to handle this case? I don't see `KeyInvalidatedException` getting thrown in this scenario.